# The facebook comment box, how to make it work correctly with URL Rewriting?

Tags: facebook, url-rewriting, facebook-comments

I added the facebook comments box to a php product page on a website that uses url rewriting.

Each product page has different url, e.g:

```
www.mysite.com/product_info.php=product1
www.mysite.com/product_info.php=product2
www.mysite.com/product_info.php=product3 and so on
```

The comment box code added to product_info.php is:

```
<div class="fb-comments"  data-href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-num-posts="20" data-width="660" data-colorscheme="dark" style="padding-left:10px;"></div>

<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

makes sure the correct url is posted to facebook Comment Moderation Tool.

I have created an iframe application on my clients facebook business page and put the comments plugin there.

How do I display the comments from the website to the iframe application on the clients facebook business page? I cant use a static url becuase each url is different on the product page.